# Eliminating unnecessary wrapper functions in `.then` handlers?

Tags: node.js, bluebird

I see the following approach often when working on certain projects that use Node.js and Bluebird.js:

```
function someAsyncOp(arg) {
    return somethingAsync(arg).then(function (results) {
        return somethingElseAsync(results);
    });
}
```

This is, creating a wrapper function/closure around another function that accepts the exact same arguments. It seems this could be written more cleanly as:

```
function someAsyncOp(arg) {
    return somethingAsync(arg).then(somethingElseAsync);
}
```

When I propose it to others, they usually like it and switch to it.

There is, however, an important caveat: if you're calling something like `object.function`, and the function relies on `this` (like `console.log` does), then `this` will lose its binding. You have to do `object.function.bind(object)`:

```
    return somethingAsync(arg).then(somethingElseAsync).catch(console.log.bind(console));
```

This does seem potentially undesirable, and the `.bind` call feels a little awkward. You can't go wrong with the let's-always-do-the-closure approach.

I can't seem to find any discussion on this on google, there doesn't seem to be anything in ESLint about unnecessary wrapper functions. I'm trying to find out more about it so here I am. I guess it's a case of I don't know what I don't know. **Is there a name for this?** (Useless use of closures?) **Any other thoughts or wisdoms?** Thank you.

**Edit**: someone's going to comment that `someAsyncOp` is also redundant, yes, it is, let's pretend it does something useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discussion here is pretty straightforward.  If your function is OK being called directly by the promise system, with the exact arguments and `this` value that will be in place when its called directly by the promise system and its return value is exactly what you want in the promise chain, then by all means, just specify the function reference directly as the `.then()` handler:

```
somethingAsync(arg).then(somethingElseAsync)
```

But, if your function isn't set up to be called directly that way, then you need a wrapper function or something like `.bind()` to fix the mismatch and call your function exactly as you want or set up the proper return value.

There's really nothing more to it than that.  It's no different than specifying any callback anywhere in Javascript.  If you have a function that already meets the specs of the callback exactly, then you can specify that function name as a direct reference with no wrapper.  But, if the function you have doesn't quite work the way the callback is designed to work, then you use a wrapper function to smooth over the mismatch.

All callback functions have the same issue with passing `obj.method` as the callback.  If your `.method` expects the `this` value to be `obj`, then you will probably have to do something to make sure that the `this` value is set accordingly before your function executes.  The callbacks in `.then()` handlers are no different than callbacks for any other Javascript/node.js function such as `setTimeout()` or `fs.readFile()` or another other function that takes a callback as an argument.  So, neither of the issues you mention is unique to promises at all.  It just so happens that promises live by callbacks so if you're trying to make method calls via a callback, you will run into the issue with the object value getting passed appropriately to the method.

FYI, it is possible to code methods so that they are permanently bound to their own object and can be passed as `obj.method`, but that can only be used in your method implementation and has some other tradeoffs.  In general, experienced Javascript developers are perfectly fine using `obj.method.bind(obj)` as the reference to pass.  Seeing the `.bind()` in the code also indicates that you're aware that you need the proper `obj` value inside the method and that you have made a provision for that.

As for some of your bolded questions or comments:

> Is there a name for this?

Not that I'm aware of.  Technically it's "passing a named reference to a previously defined function as a callback", but I doubt that's something you can search for and find useful discussion of.

> Any other thoughts or wisdoms?

For reasons, I'm not entirely sure of (though has been a topic of discussion elsewhere), Javascript programming style conventions seem to encourage the use of anonymous inline callbacks rather than defining a method or function elsewhere and then passing that named reference (like you would be more likely to do in many other languages).  Obviously, if you put the actual code to process the callback in an inline anonymous function, then neither of the issues you mention comes up.  Using arrow functions in ES6 now even allows you to preserve the current value of `this` in the inline callback.  I'm not saying that this is an answer to your question just an observation about common Javascript coding conventions.

> You can't go wrong with the let's-always-do-the-closure approach.

As you seem to already know, it's a waste to wrap something if it doesn't need wrapping.  I would vote for wrapping only when there's a mismatch between the specification for the callback and the already existing named function and there's a reason not to just fix the named function to match the specification of the callback.